# Visual Studio, install extension pylint failing with: AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute unescape

Tags: visual-studio, escaping, extension-methods, pylint, html-parser

Not possible to install some Extensions, like `pylint` or `rope`, ending always with

`AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'`

Plattform Context:

`$ lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

`$ python --version`

```
Python 3.8.3
```

`$ code     #visual studio`

```
1.53.0
8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496
x64
```

While using visual studio 'popUp' hint option to install i.e. `pylint`, in terminal initiated comand says:

```
$ /home/harry/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.1.502429796/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py  pip install -U pylint --user
```

starting well, but terminating with exception ("no attribute"):

> harry@harry-ThinkPad-X220:~/.../MICROSERVICES$ /usr/bin/python
> /home/harry/.vscoy pip install -U pylint
> --user-2021.1.502429796/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py
>
> Collecting pylint Using cached
>
> ```
>  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/13/519c1264a134beab2be4bac8dd3e64948980a5ca7833b31cf0255b21f20a/pylint-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
> ```
>
> Collecting toml>=0.7.1 (from pylint)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/6f/7120676b6d73228c96e17f1f794d8ab046fc910d781c8d151120c3f1569e/toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0 (from pylint)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/a8/5133f51967fb21e46ee50831c3f5dda49e976b7f915408d670b1603d41d6/astroid-2.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting isort<6,>=4.2.5 (from pylint)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/89/6888f573886e9dc0906ec98f1b15888de20919a142c355d7f57ebd977d36/isort-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 (from pylint)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/89/479dc97e18549e21354893e4ee4ef36db1d237534982482c3681ee6e7b57/mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting six~=1.12 (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint)   Using
> cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting wrapt~=1.11 (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint)   Using
> cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/f7/e43cefbe88c5fd371f4cf0cf5eb3feccd07515af9fd6cf7dbf1d1793a797/wrapt-1.12.1.tar.gz
> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
> status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in
> run
> wb.build(autobuilding=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
> self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 376, in
> prepare_files
> discovered_reqs.extend(self._prepare_file(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in
> _prepare_file
> abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in
> prep_for_dist
> self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in
> run_egg_info
> self.setup_py, self.name,   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in
> setup_py
> import setuptools  # noqa   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "",
> line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked   File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible   File
> "", line 259, in load_module   File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/**init**.py",
> line 14, in 
> from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
> "", line 664, in _load_unlocked   File
> "", line 627, in
> _load_backward_compatible   File "", line 259, in load_module   File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 24, in 
> from setuptools.depends import Require   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
> "", line 664, in _load_unlocked   File
> "", line 627, in
> _load_backward_compatible   File "", line 259, in load_module   File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in 
> from .py33compat import Bytecode   File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
> "", line 664, in _load_unlocked   File
> "", line 627, in
> _load_backward_compatible   File "", line 259, in load_module   File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/py33compat.py",
> line 54, in 
> unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape) AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object
> has no attribute 'unescape'

Answer (score 0):

VS was embedded in Python 3.9 and dependencies. After switch to Python 3.8.3, problem is gone, lint installed and working as expected.